# Url Rewriting in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

I'm processing Login and Register on the same page. When I click Register button I process in different Controller but I don't want to my URL.

Example: When i request

> http:localhost:1853/Account/RegisterLogin

I want to when I post if Model is invalid my URL still not change.

```
    // GET: /Account/RegisterLogin

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterLogin(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ViewData["RegisterModel"] = new RegisterModel();
        ViewData["LoginModel"] = new LoginModel();
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Gender = model.Gender, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, BirthDate = model.BirthDate, Email = model.Email }, false);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ViewData["RegisterModel"] = model;
        ViewData["LoginModel"] = new LoginModel();
        return View("RegisterLogin");
    }
```

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to post your model to the action in the same controller with the same name and add a flag to your model showing if user login or register, and according to a value of the flag do appropriate actions. It allows you to save current model state value and stay on the URL

```
    //GET /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterLogin(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(new RegisterLoginModel() { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, IsLogin = false });
    }
    //POST /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RegisterLogin(RegisterLoginModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!model.IsLogin)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Gender = model.Gender, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, BirthDate = model.BirthDate, Email = model.Email }, false);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```